# Qt cross-platform mobile ADS support?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, cross-platform, ads

I have a mobile app developed in **Qt**.

Is there a way to support **ads** with Qt?

**Thanks** in advance!

Comment: please complete your question with more info, what is ads for, example?

Comment: hey @folibis.
I simply want to ad some banner ads and an interstitial ad within my application for monetisation purpose, and I wanted to know if there's any native support for that or best practice way of doing it.
 It seems that Qt Dev answered my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a cool, newly released, first party Advertising library from **Qt**.

To use it:

1. be sure you have Qt 5.15.0 or higher installed (up to 6.2.2).
2. Install Qt Digital Advertisement plugin from either the [installer](https://qt.io/download) or from the [Maintenance Tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76KFZ.jpg) of your already installed Qt environment.
3. Copy the *profile.dat* and *configMobile.dat* files in your root project **(these files will be created specially for your account, and handed over to you from the Qt team)**
4. Edit your *qml.qrc* project file to include both of the files from point 3.

```
        ...
        <file>profile.dat</file>
        <file>configMobile.dat</file>
    </qresource>
```

5. Place the *MobileAd* qml view inside your screen qml. And you're all done!

For now Qt has a single *MobileAd* qml component, that can be manipulated at your own desire and from which you can create:

- *Banner* (Anchor) ads
- *Interstitial* (Fullscreen) ads
- *Native* (Inline) ads

In the near future the library will also support Rewarded ads.

For more details please follow the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/QtDigitalAdvertising/index.html) or blog [posts](https://www.qt.io/blog/monetizing-cross-platform-use-cases-faster-and-easier-with-qt-digital-advertising-platform).